# Webpack - steps to implement aliases inside CSS

Tags: css, webpack, sass, vue.js

Webpack allows us to create resolve aliases and use it further inside of our CSS code etc.

```
resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.vue', '.json', '.scss', '.css'],
    alias: {
      'fonts': path.join(__dirname, 'assets/fonts'),
      'images': path.join(__dirname, 'assets/images')
    }
  }
```

My question is, what are the following steps to implement aliases and use it inside LESS/SCSS ??:

1. Images: background-image: url(~imagesalias/images/image.png);
2. Fonts: src: url('~fontalias/fonts/font.ttf') format('truetype');

My current CSS/SCSS loader for DEV purposes:

```
 module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [{
          loader: "style-loader"
        }, {
          loader: "css-loader"
        }, {
          loader: "resolve-url-loader"
        }]
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [{
          loader: "style-loader"
        }, {
          loader: "css-loader"
        }, {
          loader: "resolve-url-loader"
        }, {
          loader: "sass-loader"
        }]
      }
    ]
  }
```

Answer (score 8):

I think your issue is that you are not accessing your path right.

If your webpack resolve paths are:

```
alias: {
  'fonts': path.join(__dirname, 'assets/fonts'),
  'images': path.join(__dirname, 'assets/images')
}
```

Then in order to access it in css or scss it should be:

```
background-image: url(~images/image.png);
src: url('~fonts/font.ttf') format('truetype');
```

Comment: Can you link to a resources which explains why using the tilde (~) here works?

Comment: Yes, it means that it is a module and not a relative path. Check out this Github thread. Someone asks the same question a little ways down. https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader/issues/49